# No "Going" button in Facebook event

Tags: facebook-events

I want to join this Facebook event, but there is no "Going" button:

[image: No Going button in Facebook event]

How to join the event?

Comment: This image makes me hungry for salsa...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "Going" button is hidden behind the "Interested" button:

1. Click on "Interested",
2. Click again on "Interested",
3. A menu appear, showing additional options "Going" and "Not Going",
4. Click on the "Going" option that appeared.